# Does it make sense to use dynamic mode with switch depentent mode?

Tags: windows, nic

According to the NIC teaming tutorial of itfreetraining on youtube, in the NIC teaming mode "dynamic", outbound traffic is distributed among the team members using the address hash method and inbound traffic is distributed using the hyper v method.

So far so good, but I still have some abiguities:

1. How does the dynamic hyper V method works for inbound traffic in non hyper v environment? As far as I know, when you have multiple hyper v vms and a nic team in hyper v mode, each virtual network adapter is assigned to a nic team member, using the mac address. But in my opinion this could not be applied to non hyper v environment, because there aren't any vms to distribute the traffic to. And there is only one mac address.

   2. Does is make sense to use the dynamic mode with the switch depentent mode (static and LACP)? Because the benefit of using switch depentent is that inbound traffic could be distribute. But with the hyper v method, inbound traffic is already been distributed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the dynamic hyper V method works for inbound traffic in non hyper v environment?

Not.

Distributing Payload to multiple (IP-)endpoints is not possible with no (IP-)endpoints. TCP connection distriubution over mac controllers, on the other hand is. As long as the traffic is coming from various sources (and not from a single one, like a router) this often works pretty well.

> in my opinion this could not be applied to non hyper v environment, because there aren't any vms to distribute the traffic to.

Thats right. Teaming distributes the TCP traffic over multiple interfaces (which do have multiple mac addresses), but that's done in the driver, not the IP-Stack. You application won't know about, like you vm doesn't.

> And there is only one mac address.

... for every teaming nic, or the virtual one which moves around on the physical adapters.

> Does is make sense to use the dynamic mode with the switch depentent mode 
>   (static and LACP)?

Link aggregation is not the same as Teaming. LACP doesn't do failover (by default), for example. It just fills one link, then switches transparently over to the next. No mac-addresses involved here. No connection-tracking on a higher protocol level, like on teaming.

> But with the hyper v method, inbound traffic is already been distributed.

Yes. Distribution, teaming and aggregation are just not the same thing and they are not exchangeable.

For example, if the main traffic source you are whishing to distribute to more physical adapters is a singe-mac-source (Large Server, other VM-Host, Router, Firewall ...), LACP would be your single choice.

That's why most companys use vSphere. Virtual Switches allow their uplinks to distribute traffic based on Route ID / Originating Port ID, IP hash, mac hash, LACP and PBR (policy based routing, when using NSX).

Comment: `TCP connection distriubution over mac controllers`
So in the dynamic NIC teaming mode inbound traffic network streams are going through a specific assigned NIC team member? And this allocation is based on the destination mac-address?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, it's static, but dynamically assigned (aka 'every time maybe another nic in the team'). The algorithm takes the (hopefully) best of each of the two modes and combines them into a single mode. Outbound traffic is distributed based on a hash of the TCP *Ports* and IP addresses (because outgoing source mac can be altered) and inbound traffic is distributed as static ('assigned' traffic). You can see this when monitoring all the assigned switch ports from your nic team.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I understand you correctly in the dynamic mode inbound traffic is distribute using the mac address and outbound traffic is distribute using a hash? And all the network streams could switch to another member, depending on the work load. But then it would not make sense to use the switch depentent mode with the dynamic mode, because in the dynamic mode, inbound traffic is already been distributed.

Comment: The 'switch depentent mode' ist just a LACP (802.3ad) bond. LACP does *not distribute* any traffic (see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Aggregation). It just aggregates two or more phy ports into one logical port - adding one after another, load dependend.

Comment: Dankeschön. So in a switch depentent mode (link aggregation) the switch is responsible for the inbound traffic and uses all the connected ports to forward the traffic. And in a switch indepentent mode all incoming trafic is going through one member (except in hyper-mode)?

Comment: 'uses all the connected ports to forward the traffic' (if necessary, yes). 'indepentent mode all incoming trafic is going through one member' (per connection, yes).